# Electric motors with both stater and rotor as electromagnets

Tags: motor, dc-motor, electromagnetism, induction-motor

I am totally new to the Electrical area. I wanted to do a project on Electric car which needs an Electric motor which is highly powerful and efficient. Are there any motors which have both stater and rotor as electromagnets without the brushes?. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want.  But in general, induction motors are powerful and don't use permanent magnets or brushes. How many kW do you need? What kind of rpm? Do you have a three-phase supply, or are you limited to domestic mains voltage?

Comment: Yes, several. But you have to communicate electrical power to the rotor without using brushes : are slip rings cheating? If so, then use induction, i.e. make the whole motor a transformer where the rotor is secondary to the stator's primary.

Comment: The project is to make an Electric car. And as far as i have researched on the motors i find that the Three phase AC and BLDC  as well as Brushed DC are having merits and demerits in efficiency. I want to know that whether there is motor that are having both rotor and stater as electromagnets (advantage from brushed DC motor) , brush less( advantage of both BLDC and AC). if no are there any Induction DC motors? Thanks

Comment: you can't have "DC Induction motor's" They work because of the transformer action between the stator and the rotor and thus you need AC on the stator

Comment: AC Mains Primary Generators are brushless & can have electromagnets for both the stator & rotor in *both* stator/motor pairs! Have a look at [this article](http://electricalbaba.com/brushless-excitation-system/) for an overview of the tech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state you are after "powerful" and "efficient" ... what power level?

You are right to consider machine topologies that do not involve brushes as these are inefficient, wear out but also limit maximum rotor velocity

Mechanical power is the product of shaft torque and rotor velocity: \$P = T\omega \$ How you generate the maximum power is a system architecture point of view. Higher torque or higher speed.

There are a number of machine topologies that do not require brushes to provide rotor magnetic flux.

1. Permanent Magnet Synchronous Machine
2. Switched Reluctance machine
3. Wound rotor, rotating rectifier synchronous machine
4. Squirrel cage induction machine

One of the most power efficient topologies is the PMSM, especially when optimised and excited with AC - PMAC. The reason for this is part of your required flux generation is already provided by the magnets on the rotor.

At some point however the use of permanent magnets is not feasible (temperature etc....)

Switched Reluctance is another topology and these come into their own at very high speeds and environmentally harsh environments Not as power dense or efficient as a PMSM (96% compared to 91%) but still a very viable topology, chosen more due to fault tolerance or environment.

Wound rotor, rotating diode synchronous machines are the 3rd type. A DC current is supplied to the aux windings & via a rotating transformer, the main exciter receives power. AC is supplied to provide zero speed torque. This type of machines are predominantly used in power generation.

Squirrel cage induction machines.  The workhorse of industry. Rotor flux is generated via transformer action between the stator and the rotor. Reasonably poor efficiency. Field orientated COntrol can improve operating point efficiency w.r.t. variable speed control, but it still losses to PMSM